# Why is Subdivision surface doing this? (unwanted bumps/creases)

Tags: mesh, geometry, subdivision-surface

Her head is meant to be smooth but subdivision surface is adding strange nubs and creases as shown below:

The model is being mirrored if that has anything to do with it.

[image: "Horns"]

[image: "Horns" 2]

[image: Creases]

Comment: See if you have fippled normals. Go to Overlays (top right) and check Face Orientations.

Comment: THAT WAS IT! thanks a million. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so as I've just learned from Vagabonk: This is caused by *flipped normals.*

To see if the normals are flipped, **while in Object mode**, locate the "**overlays**" tab in the top right of the screen. (the one with two circles intersecting)

After clicking the overlays tab, tick the checkbox next to the option "**face orientation**" and the inversed faces will be an opposing color.

In my case, the interior faces were red, the exteriors were blue.

Now, enter **edit mode** and use face selection by hitting "**3**" on the keyboard, not the numpad.

While still in **edit mode**, after selecting the problem faces, click the **"mesh"** option in the top left of your screen, hover over the "**normals**" option, and click "**flip.**"

This should now have all the exterior faces as the same color, and if your problem was the same as mine, it will have smoothed the jagged vertices.

Comment: You can also select all with the 'A' key then use Shift-N to recalculate the normals which is somewhat faster!

Comment: Important tip, many thanks indeed. ^^